# Do players get yellow cards when they remove their jersey during celebrations?

Tags: rules, football, officiating, uniform

If a player receives a first caution (yellow card) during the game and the same player scores a goal and removes his jersey will he be dismissed from the field of play and shown a red card?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, it happen numerous of times.

It's like every other yellow card,
look at this from [FIFA laws of the games](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/affederation/federation/81/42/36/lawsofthegameen.pdfJhbv3VVA&sig2=FhVOTOyeHVirYTyk1h-LjA):

> #### Celebration of a Goal
>
> While it is permissible for a player to demonstrate his joy when a goal has been 
>   scored, the celebration must not be excessive.
>   Reasonable celebrations are allowed, but the practice of choreographed 
>   celebrations is not to be encouraged when it results in excessive time-wasting 
>   and referees are instructed to intervene in such cases.
>
> A player must be cautioned if:
>
> - in the opinion of the referee, he makes gestures which are provocative, 
>     derisory or inﬂammatory
> - he climbs on to a perimeter fence to celebrate a goal being scored
> - he removes his shirt or covers his head with his shirt
> - he covers his head or face with a mask or other similar item
>
> Leaving the ﬁeld of play to celebrate a goal is not a cautionable offence in itself 
>   but it is essential that players return to the field of play as soon as possible.
>   Referees are expected to act in a preventative manner and to exercise common 
>   sense in dealing with the celebration of a goal.

Two examples from the FA Premier League:
- [Arjen Robben of Chelsea](http://news.bbc.co.uk/sport1/hi/football/rules_and_equipment/4616854.stm)
- [Ross Wallace of Sunderland](http://www.hartlepoolmail.co.uk/news/gaffer-happy-with-players-ross-faces-ban-1-1013598)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The players usually gets booked for celebrating the goal by removing his shirt due to the disciplinary reasons. And the referees spare no mercy to issue the second yellow card (first card in the earlier match) & send the player off. There have been no complaints from the players & the managers about this.